# Kendo Grid Fails With EDMX Update

Tags: asp.net, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo grid running on a MVC application. The grid worked fine until I added a foreign keyed table to the DB Model. After updating the EDMX with the newly linked foreign key table, without making any other changes, my grid shows no data. I'm looking for an explanation why this new relation disrupts the data I had working correctly previously.

Comment: there  can be so many things Luke . you changed the data model . what you  r grid is doing is it just doing read or you are doing all CRUD op . if something else is being done other than read then definately you have to consider the foreign key change

Comment: post code of your entity model and controller as well as grid

Comment: also sql table relation